# Cloud Run : gcloud run deploy does not route the traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I deployed two Cloud Run services (staging and production) using GCP Cloud Build with this command:

```
entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'app', '--project', '$PROJECT_ID', '--image', 'image:$COMMIT_SHA', '--region', 'us-central1', '--allow-unauthenticated', '--memory' , '256Mi', '--update-env-vars', 'ENV=production']
```

I noticed that the same command has different behavior on staging and production. On one of my services, the traffic is not routed automatically to the newest revision.

```
Already have image (with digest): 
Deploying container to Cloud Run service 
Deploying...
Setting IAM Policy..............done
Creating Revision..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done
Done.

Service [] revision [] has been deployed and is serving 0 percent of traffic.

I am missing this step : 

Routing traffic......done
```

I checked the cloud run `service.yaml` and the traffic argument is set :

```
 traffic:
  - latestRevision: true
    percent: 100
```

If I run the same command on GCP console, everything works as expected.

Question:
Why `gcloud run deploy` does not route the traffic when I am running from Cloud Build pipeline ? ( I do not have `--no traffic` flag set)

Comment: Did you play on the UI with the traffic splitting?

Comment: No, I did not play with traffic splitting?

Comment: Are you gcloud sdk up to date?

Comment: I am just trying to deploy from cloud buil but the thraffic is not routed. The same command works fine from cloud shell. This is the command `gcloud run deploy prod --project xxxx --image image:xxx --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --memory 256Mi --update-env-vars ENV=production`

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172165141

There are two modes available to you: route traffic to latest revision or manually distribute it.
If you switched to manual routing the service stays like this until you decide to revert it back with `gcloud run services update-traffic testservice --platform="managed" --to-latest.`. This is made to keep it simple and fight ambiguity and unexpected traffic switch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using Google Cloud-Build:

```
steps:
  - name: build
    ...
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID,$_LABELS
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update-traffic
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--to-latest'
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Route-Traffic
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _PLATFORM: managed
  _SERVICE_NAME: my-service
  _DEPLOY_REGION: us-central1
  _GCR_HOSTNAME: us.gcr.io
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed
  - my-service
```

Take a look in [here](https://medium.com/@effoeffi/how-to-adjust-the-traffic-assignments-for-a-cloud-run-service-cad057554272) for more details :)